# How do I programmatically turn on/off restrictions on IOS / iphone / ipad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mdm, parental-control

What is the simplest way to programmatically turn on/off restrictions on IOS/iphone/ipad?  Specifically, I want to be able to toggle the Apps restrictions between "Don't Allow Apps" and "Allow All Apps".  It seems that most parental control software uses a MDM profile to accomplish this which is fine but I can't seem to find any parental control software with a public API nor any instructions on how to actually accomplish this on my own.

Comment: If a public API were available for that, wouldn't every app use it to remove restrictions on themselves?

Comment: I know it's 100% possible as there are dozens of apps that do it.  I'm not asking if it's possible but rather *how* to do it.

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking for; are you asking how you can create a system that allows you to manage restrictions? If so, then you will need to build an MDM server and use that to push updated profiles. Or, are you asking for an existing MDM server than has an API that you can use to trigger the push of updated profiles?  If so, then asking for recommendations is off-topic. I know that Microsoft InTune has web service APIs but I don't know for sure that you can use them to push new profiles, but I would be surprised if you can't